# ViewPager2 fragments with Recyclerview, inside a ScrollView is not getting height attribute as wrap_content

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-viewpager2

I am trying set three different fragments in ViePager2, inside a ScrollView, all three Fragments has a same RecyclerView, which are product lists with different heights, I am looking for a help to set the height of these RecyclerViews dynamically.

**Activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">...//some_code_here

    <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:fillViewport="true">...//some_code_here

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recycler_top_sale"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
          android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**RecyclerView.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:background="@color/colorWhite"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
      app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

      ...//some_code_here

  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think, you should have fixed height of viewpager and try to scroll the data inside a viewpager,
As viewpager has 3 fragments and each fragment's recyclerView item count can be different.